# How to extract data from PDF form and transfer to SharePoint Online List without using Power Apps AI Builder or Muhimbi PDF in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, powerapp, pdf

I am seeking architectural guidance. Without access to Power Apps AI Builder or Muhimbi PDF, what other option do I have to extract data from PDF forms and populate a SharePoint Online List.

It is also preferred that each of the PDF forms be attached to the SP list item. Also, although not a must, it is preferred that I stick with modern experience.

Comment: There are several JavaScript libraries you could use to parse or generate PDF files. Unfortunately I don't have a recommendation or any sample code. I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: I suppose you got issues because of additional licenses apart from your current one. I can't recommend much, but you can try Encodian to read the PDF freely with Power Automate using their Free plan, but it's up to 50 actions per month, if it suits you.